# What happens to position of a small particle that's orbiting a massive object suddenly experiences a change in mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Let's say we have a tiny object with mass M1 that's orbiting around another object with massive mass M2 at a particular velocity V1, a distance R1 away from the mass M2.

What would happen to the orbit of M1 if the mass of M2 is suddenly increases or decreases? Also, as it happens, the moment the mass changes instantaneously, the radius between M1 and M2 remains unchanged. We can assume M2's mass changes due to its density changing and not its radius.

I'm conceptually trying to understand what would happen. If M2 decreases, I think that M1 would eventually escape the orbit around M2. If M2 increases, my thinking is that M1 would experience an increase in velocity and its orbit would get closer to M2 and if M2 increases even more, at some amount of M2, M1 would crash into M1.

It would be fantastic if you could explain with an equation as well.

Comment: Do you consider that in vacuum two objects with different masses fall at the same rate?

Comment: @KurtG. Yes, in a vacuum, two objects far away from each other with no influence on each other's spacetime curvature would fall at the same rate. 

However, in my question above, the two objects are in some sense "bound" to each other. As the mass of M2 increases (massive objects), its spacetime curvature lines would be more directed inwards, and M1 and other smaller objects in its orbit would be pulled towards it with greater force. Kind of like a growing black hole, I think.

Comment: to answer this we would need to know how the extra mass was moving as it arrived

Comment: As described this question is physically impossible. The object cannot just magically gain mass. It must gain mass through some process. The details of that process affect the answer

Comment: @Dale could you please give a couple of examples of mass gaining through different processes and how that would effect the orbit? One way I could think of is by a bunch of smaller objects that collide M2 and causes mass to be accumulated and the smaller objects compress M2 with the resultant force and doesn't change the size of the mass M2, only it's mass.

Comment: @Blackbird yes that was what I was thinking. The details of the smaller objects matter. Do they come in from one side or the other? Do they come in spherically symmetric? Do they have some variation in momentum or velocity or what? That is what you need to describe to obtain an answer

Comment: The "cleanest" method of mass addition would be to imagine a converging uniform spherical shell of total mass $\Delta M$ centered at $M_2$.  Before it passes $M_1$, $M_1$ only feels the influence of $M_2$.  Afterwards, it experiences the gravitational field of a point mass $M_2 + \Delta M$ at the same location.  In other words, from $M_1$'s perspective, it's as though the central mass suddenly increases.

Answer (score 1):

with  the vis-viva equation and assuming a circle motion

you obtain that the tangential velocity is:

$$v^2=G\,(m+M)\,\frac 1r$$
where r is the circle radius, thus if $~M\mapsto M+\Delta M$

$$v_{M+\Delta M}^2=v_M^2\,\frac{M+\Delta M}{M}$$

if M is increased the velocity is increased

Comment: could you please clarify which M's your masses are? Is it M1 or M2? Thanks

Comment: @Blackbird leave M constant and $~m\mapsto m+\Delta m~$ you obtain that

$v_{m+\Delta m}^2=v_m^2\,\frac{M+\Delta m}{M}~$  thus if m increased the velocity increased too